# Filtering data on 4 Laravel's Model

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have 4 models with specified purpose.

- Merchant

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Merchant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
        'pinpoint',
        'latitude',
        'longitude',
        'open_hour',
        'close_hour',
        'tax_restaurant',
        'tax_service',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function produk()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Produk::class, 'merchant_produks');
    }
}
```

- Produk

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Produk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'kategori_id',
        'name',
        'combo',
        'price',
        'description',
        'option',
        'picture',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function kategori()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kategori::class);
    }

    public function merchant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Merchant::class, 'merchant_produks');
    }
}
```

- Merchant_produk (as pivot of Merchant and Produk)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MerchantProduk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'produk_id',
        'merchant_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
}
```

- Kategori

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kategori extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function produk()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Produk::class);
    }
}
```

- Controller's Function

```
    public function selectedmerchant($kategoriID, $merchantID)
    {
        // $data = Merchant::with([
        //     'produk' => function ($query) use ($kategoriID) {
        //         $query->wherePivot('kategori_id', $kategoriID);
        //     }
        // ])->where('id', $merchantID)
        //     ->get();
        // $data = Produk::with(['merchant' => function ($query) use ($merchantID) {
        //     $query->wherePivot('merchant_id', $merchantID);
        // }])->where('kategori_id', $kategoriID)->get();
        $data = Merchant::with('produk')->where('id', $merchantID)->get();
        return JsonFormater::buildResponse(200, 'success', $data);
        // return JsonFormater::buildResponse(200, 'success', [
        //     'kategori' => $kategoriID,
        //     'merchant' => $merchantID,
        // ]);
    }
```

What i want to do is to filtering the data with 2 parameters viz KategoriID and MerchantID.

I already try to using wherePivot, but, i realize it cannot filtering data by kategori id.

this is temporary result of function :
[image: temporary result]

Comment: This laravel package is helpful if you are filtering data on multiple models without further engineering, need to just put our usual query, have a look at it.
https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-cross-eloquent-search

Comment: Create kategorie relation in merchant model as hasManyThrough2LinkTables. Then you can use where on the relation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541680/how-to-create-laravel-8-custom-relation-hasmanythrough-2-and-3-link-tables-so-in

Answer (score 0):

Create kategorie relation in merchant model as hasManyThrough2LinkTables. Then you can use where on the relation.
[How to create Laravel 8 custom relation HasManyThrough 2 and 3 Link Tables so involving 4 or 5 tables in total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541680/how-to-create-laravel-8-custom-relation-hasmanythrough-2-and-3-link-tables-so-in)